# SQL query error in Marketing cloud

Tags: sql

```
SELECT A.EmailAddress,
case when  A.RegisteredProduct1 = 'Yes' then  'Yes'
end     B.RegisteredProduct1
FROM WebinarMasterDE B
Join  WebResponseDe A  ON  A.EmailAddress = B.EmailAddress
```

When i am trying to run this SQL query in Marketing cloud it is giving me the error Incorrect syntax near '.'. Unable to figure out the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to get the `case-when` right. This is the right `case-when`:

```
case when  A.RegisteredProduct1 = 'Yes' then  'Yes' else B.RegisteredProduct1 end
```

And this is the query that you need:

```
SELECT A.EmailAddress,
case when  A.RegisteredProduct1 = 'Yes' then  'Yes' else B.RegisteredProduct1 end
FROM WebinarMasterDE B
Join  WebResponseDe A  ON  A.EmailAddress = B.EmailAddress
```

However, the easiest syntax-level fix is to add a missing comma:

```
SELECT A.EmailAddress,
case when  A.RegisteredProduct1 = 'Yes' then  'Yes'
end, -- this is it, the missing comma
     B.RegisteredProduct1 -- this is a new column
FROM WebinarMasterDE B
Join  WebResponseDe A  ON  A.EmailAddress = B.EmailAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the B. from the alias name

```
SELECT A.EmailAddress,
case when  A.RegisteredProduct1 = 'Yes' then  'Yes'
end  RegisteredProduct1  --Remove the B. from here as it is an alias name
FROM WebinarMasterDE B
Join  WebResponseDe A  ON  A.EmailAddress = B.EmailAddress
```